# What's the difference between left side and right side of the equals in a LINQ join

Tags: linq

When doing a join in Linq such as

`from c in customers join x in somelistofcustomers on x.Id equals c.Id`

you'll get the error

> x is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'. Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'

Simple enough to do, but I would like some clarification why x is not in scope on the left side, but somehow is in scope on the right side of `equals`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is to do with the way that LINQ is expanded by the compiler into the underlying extension methods.

Your query is being translated into:

```
customers.Join(somelistofcustomers, c => x.Id, x => c.Id, (c, x) => ...)
```

The two lambda expressions `c => x.Id` & `x => c.Id` clearly have their local variables out of scope. Since LINQ is just a nice sugar coating over the actual calls the compiler correcly complains that the variable is out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a convention, basically the structure of a join is as follows

```
from identifier in {outer-sequence} 
join identifier2 in {inner-sequence} 
on {outer-key-selector} equals {inner-key-selector}
```

`identifier` and `{outer-key-selector}` are paired, and so are `identifier2` and `{inner-key-selector}` - you can't switch the order, because their position is fixed in the join syntax.